# Redirect Com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, axios

Estou fazendo um sistema que faz uma requisição `ajax` com axios. Até aí td bem, consegui fazer a requisição `GET` e listar todos os itens na tela, em uma tabela. Nessa tabela tem um botão **Ver Item**, que devo redirecionar para outra página onde vou mostrar apenas o item em questão. Faço isso com `PHP`, mas estou estudando `Javascript` e gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso.

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post')
.then(function(response){
    jQuery.each(response.data, function(key, value){ 
        //REQUISIÇÃO AJAX COM AXIOS
        jQuery.each(value, function(label, answer){                 
            display = '\
                <tr>\
                    <td>' + value.id + '</td>\
                    <td>' + value.title + '</td>\
                    <td>\
                        <button id="btn'+ value.id +'" class="btn btn-primary">Ver detalhes</button>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>'
            }); 
            $('#tbody').append(display);

            //BOTÃO QUE DEVE REDIRECIONAR PARA OUTRA PÁGINA
            $('#btn' + value.id ).click(function() {
                window.location.href = "post.html";
            });
        }); 
});
```

Comment: é isso mesmo... `window.location.href`, qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Comment: Por que ao invés de criar um botão você não cria um link (`<a>`) com o atributo `href`? :)

Comment: minha dúvida é como passar os parâmetros para a outra página, preciso fazer um get com o id do item ou posso enviar os parâmetros direto dessa página e apenas ler ela na outra página. Se sim, como fazer isso??

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é você enviar o `id` para a pagina via `query string` exemplo:

```
www.seusite.com/detalhePost.php?id=1
```

Na outra pagina você deve pegar esse id e buscar os detalhes dele com outra requisição, seja `ajax`, `axios` ou `php` mesmo.
e a partir dai você mostrar os detalhes do seu post.

você tambem consegue enviar o objeto inteiro pela url observe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sugiro você utilizar um padrao chamado **REST API**

[Sobre Rest API](http://blog.caelum.com.br/rest-principios-e-boas-praticas/)

e ao inves de `www.seusite.com/detalhePost.php?id=1` voce pode fazer `www.seusite.com/detalhePost/1`

e fazer o bom uso dos metodos `HTTP => GET, POST, PUT e DELETE`